# RIGHT of CHARINDEX not selecting correctly

Tags: sql, charindex

I am trying to parse out a last name field that may have two last names that are separated by either a blank space  ' ' or a hyphen '-' or it may only have one name.

Here is what I'm using to do that:

```
select      top 1000
            BENE_FIRST_NAME, 
            BENE_LAST_NAME,
            FirstNm =
                case
                    when BENE_FIRST_NAME like '% %' then
                        left(BENE_FIRST_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', BENE_FIRST_NAME))
                    when BENE_FIRST_NAME like '%-%' then
                        left(BENE_FIRST_NAME, CHARINDEX('-', BENE_FIRST_NAME))
                    else BENE_FIRST_NAME
                end,
            LastNm =
                case
                    when BENE_LAST_NAME like '% %' then
                        right(BENE_LAST_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', BENE_LAST_NAME))
                    when BENE_LAST_NAME like '%-%' then
                        right(BENE_LAST_NAME, CHARINDEX('-', BENE_LAST_NAME))
                    else BENE_LAST_NAME
                end,
            CharIndxDash = CHARINDEX('-', BENE_LAST_NAME),
            CharIndxSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', BENE_LAST_NAME)
from        xMIUR_Elig_Raw_v3
```

Here are some results:

| BENE_FIRST_NAME | BENE_LAST_NAME | FirstNm | LastNm | CharIndxDash | CharIndxSpace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JUANA | PEREZ-MARTINEZ | JUANA | RTINEZ | 6 | 0 |
| EMILIANO | PICENO ESPINOZA | EMILIANO | SPINOZA | 0 | 7 |
| JULIAN | NIETO-CARRENO | JULIAN | ARRENO | 6 | 0 |
| EMILY | SALMERON TERRIQUEZ | EMILY | TERRIQUEZ | 0 | 9 |

The CHARINDEX seems to be selecting the correct position but it is not bringing in all of the CHARs to the right of that position. Sometimes it works like in the last record. But sometimes it is off by 1. And sometimes it is off by 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using SSMS v18.8...don't jump down my throat.

Comment: Do you have any spaces after the last name or double spaces between some of the names that may be causing your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select part of a last name after space/hyphen, you need to get right part of the string with length = `total_lenght - space_position`:

```
  ...
  LastNm =
            case
                when BENE_LAST_NAME like '% %' then
                    right(BENE_LAST_NAME, LEN(BENE_LAST_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', BENE_LAST_NAME))
                when BENE_LAST_NAME like '%-%' then
                    right(BENE_LAST_NAME, LEN(BENE_LAST_NAME) -CHARINDEX('-', BENE_LAST_NAME))
                else BENE_LAST_NAME
            end,
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I should've seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Your last name logic doesn't make sense..

RIGHT takes N chars from the right of the string

CHARINDEX gives the position of a char from the left of the string

You can't use it to find a position from left and then take that number of chars from the right of the string

Here's a name:

```
JOHN MALKOVICH
```

The space is at 5. If you take 5 chars from the right, you get OVICH. The shorter the name before the space and the longer the name after the space, the fewer chars you get from the last name

Perhaps you mean to put a LEN in there so you take the string length minus the index of the space.. You can also use it in a call to SUBSTRING as the start index, and tell SQLS to take 9999 chars (of any number longer than the remaining string) and it will take up to the end of the string

```
SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, 9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code by a lot. Consider below with a different but representative sample data

```
with data (name) as 

(select 'first-last' union select 'first last' union select 'firstlast'),

data_prepped (name, indx) as

(select name,coalesce(nullif(charindex(' ', name)+charindex('-', name),0),len(name))
 from data)


select name, 
       left(name, indx-1) as part1,
       right(name, indx) as part2
from data_prepped
```